# Show that $A=cI$ for c non-zero real number.

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, irreducible-polynomials

We have A 2×2 matrix with real numbers. We know that there is an odd n such that $A^{n}=I$. Show that $A=cI$ for c non-zero real number.
We can find easily that $det(A)=1$. I took the polynomial $P(x)=x^{n}-1$. So $P(x)=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1)$
A is solution for P(x). So the minimal polynomial $m_{a}|P(x)$. We find that $m_{a}$ can be $(x-1)$ wich shows $A=I$. From here I dont know how to continue with that cyclotronic polynomial.

Comment: Take the matrix rotation : $$A = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \frac{2\pi}{3} & - \sin \frac{2\pi}{3} \\ \sin \frac{2\pi}{3} & \cos \frac{2\pi}{3} \end{pmatrix}$$ we have $A^3  = I$ but there is no $c$ such that $A = c I$.

Comment: Yeah the problem looked to me suspicious. Thanks!

Comment: The only odd $n$ such that $x^n-1$ has a quadratic cyclotomic factor is $n=3$.